# TiDB vs Vitess - How should I base my decision?

Tags: mysql, scalability

I need a scalable MySQL-compatable solution that can scale to multiple installs across a network, handling millions of records on several tables with tens of thousands of concurrent requests per-second. I don't want to rely on pre-rolled cloud solutions.

I have come across TiDB and Vitess. These two are especially important for me because I want to use Acra for security. I found [this blog post](https://blog.yugabyte.com/rise-of-globally-distributed-sql-databases-redefining-transactional-stores-for-cloud-native-era/) which puts Vitess under Distributed SQL 1.0 – NewSQL stating "Poor Fault Tolerance" and "No Multi-Shard ACID Transactions." Then, tidb under "Distributed SQL 2.0 – Globally Distributed SQL."

Under tidb I see "This choice essentially makes TiDB unfit for multi-region deployments since majority of transactions in a random-access OLTP workload will now experience high WAN latency for getting a timestamp from the global timestamp oracle running in a different region." This is concerning though idk if it's still true.

I have not been able to find any benchmarks comparing the two. I'm not sure how to evaluate which to use. I have a lot of records, about 20 tables and lots of joins. Pretty standard really except that I'm to a point where I know I need to expand beyond one dedicated server, both for more hardware and presumably fault tolerance.

How do Vitess and tidb compare/contrast?

Comment: One InnoDB instance can handle what you describe. Do you know what vitess/tidb features you need?

Comment: I want redundancy which I don't currently have. I'd like to not pay a big performance price for it. I'd also like to have something like this in place so that once I need a second machine for performance, I've already got the right software running ahead of time. Of course the need for redundancy dictates that I do it now anyway.

Comment: Let's take a different approach.  Please provide the table definition and a query that will be frequently executed.  We can discuss how to make that query perform well, and discuss the issues with scaling it.

Comment: Keep in mind that any competing database vendor is ultimately limited by I/O speed.